# The greatest $M$ that $\sqrt[5]{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{b}{c+d}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{c}{d+e}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{d}{e+a}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{e}{a+b}}>M$

Tags: calculus, inequality, contest-math

> Find infimum of expression$\sqrt[5]{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{b}{c+d}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{c}{d+e}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{d}{e+a}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{e}{a+b}}$ for $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

I tried a lot of methods, i.e. AM-GM inequality, Radon inequality, rearrangement, I searched for some refinements of Nesbitt inequality, tried Lagrange Multipliers, but the computations are very messy. I noticed that this inequality is homogenous, but the form of the fractions isn't nice.

I would be very grateful for any hint, sources which deals with this problems, papers, helpful approaches etc. (not solution).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Problems such as this should include not just a list of methods, but also the source and motivation of the problem.   Why do you suspect there are books and papers which deal with this specific problem?

Comment: If this is a contest problem, you should list what contest the problem is from.

Comment: @Brian Tung This problem is similar to very many contest problems. I think it's enough. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/contest-math/info

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I'd agree it isn't mandatory, but it's still useful context.  This seems like a specific problem, and I'm curious about it.

Comment: @Brian Tung It's similar to the know contest problem with three variables: For all non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0$ prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}\geq2.$ There are another similar to starting problem contest problems.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: That seems easier; in fact, I worked on that one to help me to figure out the case for $n = 5$.  If the OP is merely inspired by that problem, it's still useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

It's not solution, but maybe it will help.
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[5]{\frac{a}{b+c}}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[5]{a}}{\sqrt[5]b+\sqrt[5]c}>$$
$$>\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[5]a}{\sqrt[5]a+\sqrt[5]b+\sqrt[5]c+\sqrt[5]d+\sqrt[5]e}=1.$$ Also, for $c=e\rightarrow0^+$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[5]{\frac{a}{b+c}}\rightarrow\sqrt[5]{\frac{a}{b}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{b}{d}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{d}{a}}\geq3,$$ which says that $1\leq M\leq3.$

Also, since $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[5]{\frac{a}{b+c}}>\sqrt[5]{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}}=\sqrt[5]{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt[5]{\frac{(a+b+c+d+e)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab+ac)}}\geq \sqrt[5]{\frac{5}{2}},$$ we obtain:
$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{5}{2}}\leq M\leq3.$$